# i want to remove windows 8 and windows 7 from my triple boot with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall

Right now in my bootloader i have 3 OS namely ubuntu 12.04 , windows 7 and windows 8 . 
i have a virus in my pc and so windows 7 and 8 dont work. i want only ubuntu 12.04 on my pc right now and then after cleaning my pc free from viruses i may dual boot it with windows for gaming purposes.
so how do i remove windows 7 and windows 8 and just keep ubuntu as my operating system ? 
Please help.

[image: img]

Comment: how do i upload the screenshot ?

Comment: i think the partition is faulty , it is not readable , i think it has been corrupted badly . when i am trying to delete the partition it shows "Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 5" . Does this relate to the partition name ? because the partition having windows 8 is dev/sda5. i deleted windows 7 partition successfuully . But i cant even mount this partition now so cant delete the boot files . :(

Comment: haha. i coundl't delete the partition and so i formatted it to ext4 and then again to ntfs and now it is blank :P haha . lol . how did that happen ? i still cant delete the partition thougn

Comment: [IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/316ug60.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the Windows partitions with gparted.
Make sure to open gparted as root.

if you don't have gparted installed install it by typing `sudo apt-get install gpareted` in a terminal.

Start it with `sudo gparted` and edit your partitions.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail.? i'm a noob in ubuntu..

Comment: that's not really possible.

Comment: that just was a wubi directory. sorry for that. Can you explain the process to me ? i'm not that good with terminal commands

Comment: open a command line, execure `sudo gparted` and delete the windows partitions from there on.

Comment: and is there a way to edit the partition sizes ? not with the command line but is there an application for it ?

Comment: oh .. lol.. sorry for the silly questions

Comment: sudo gparted: command not found

Comment: why is it saying that the command not found ..i typed sudo gparted in the terminal ..gave my password and it says command not found

Comment: @Alvar he edited the post which I was referring to as impossible. @ankit get gparted. `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: okay so after i format this partition will this become unallocated space ?

Comment: the partition is locked i guess .. because the delete option is greyed

Comment: @Alvar what should i do now ? i cant delete the partition it seems

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way for you to do it is trough graphical interface:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Afther you install the program you will be presented with all the boot options, remove rom that list windows 8 and 7.
Afther that you have to physicaly remove them from your hardware.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Now press the super key, type gparted and open it.
You should get something like this:

[image]

Now just make sure you chose the corect partition(for windows 8 aor 7) and press the delete button and you will delete that partition.

For a graphical tutorial just go on youtube : [GParted Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb54TsYI6UA)

Comment: but they have a transparent key drawn to the left of the file system and the delete option is greyed off

Comment: what shall i do now?

Comment: What do you mean it is grayed of? did you watch the youtube tutorial? mayby you are doing something wrong

Comment: when i am deleting the 2nd partition , it is saying Please unmount any logical partitions having a number higher than 5

Comment: Pls provide a screenshot with what you want to do. I think the problem is, if you have a partition for example sda2 and another one sda3, and sda3 was made from sda2 i think you have to delete first sda3 and then sda2

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution, only takes 10-15 minutes.
It worked for me several times.

SOLUTION:

1. GET A WINDOWS 7 OR 8 INSTALLATION DISK.
2. BOOT WITH THAT DISK{just like windows installation}
3. When installation reaches hard disk partitions menu......
4. Format the drives in which windows 7 and 8 are contained.....

NOTE DO NOT FORMAT OTHER DRIVES.
IF THE FORMAT DOESN'T COMPLETES. JUST DELETE THE PARTITION AND RECREATE IT.

Comment: Yesssss.... Ur,,, Right Alwar

Comment: Thanx Alwar.... I will make improvements

Comment: Wow! Alwar.... You have 5 golden badges ........
what a highness.....

Comment: i dont have any installation discs , both had been installled with iso files

Comment: Then just burn the iso in DVD.......and then try

Comment: in gparted the partitions are locked..and the delete option is disabled

Comment: delete option is always disabled for partitions containing boot files
------Listen what i'm telling u.... just burn the windows iso in a disk and follws the instruction given by me...